# How to recursively find all similar tags in an ElementTree and also their level?

Tags: python, recursion, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have multiple trees, each tree structure will look different.

What I am trying to achieve is to find all children with the tag "Serial Number" and what their "level" is and who their parent "Serial Number" is.

For instance with the following XML

```
  **<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <Product Name="Product A">
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Year>2009</year>
        <Serial Number>AB102</Serial Number>
        <Document>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <Serial Number>BB103</SerialNumber>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <Country>IA</Country>
            <Serial Number>CC102</Serial Number>
                 <Document>
                     <Serial Number>DD102</Serial Number>
                 </Document>
        </Document>
   </Product Name>
</data>
```

I want to fetch

```
Serial Number | Parent Serial Number | Level
   AB102             root                0 
   BB103             AB102               1   
   CC102             AB102               1  
   DD102             CC102               2
```

My first idea is to try and implement some sort of recursive function, but I have a hard time trying to understand the logic I have to set-up to make it work. Has anyone else done something similar or know how to correctly implement this recursive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to make a few changes to the XML provided (due to it being invalid xml) with spaces in tags and some mismatched spelling; but the following should give you a starting point if nothing else (the changed XML is below):

## XML (example.xml content)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <ProductName Name="Product A">
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Year>2009</Year>
        <SerialNumber>AB102</SerialNumber>
        <Document>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <SerialNumber>BB103</SerialNumber>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <Country>IA</Country>
            <SerialNumber>CC102</SerialNumber>
                 <Document>
                     <SerialNumber>DD102</SerialNumber>
                 </Document>
        </Document>
   </ProductName>
</data>
```

## Code

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def process_children(tree_in, parent_name, depth):
    next_depth = depth + 1
    for c in list(tree_in):
        if(c.tag == 'SerialNumber'):
            print('{0} | {1} | {2}'.format(c.text, parent_name, depth))
            parent_name = c.text
        process_children(c, parent_name, next_depth)

process_children(root, 'root', -1)
```

## Result

```
AB102 | root  | 0
BB103 | AB102 | 1
CC102 | AB102 | 1
DD102 | CC102 | 2
```

Comment: Hi, this looks very promising. Just one question, how would I treat the case when I have a "SerialNumber" tag as the child of root? I have a few of these cases which this script then misses.